# Incorrect Date conversion when using moment

Tags: momentjs

Not sure if there is a problem with my code but it seems like the Date is incorrect when using moment.  Here's my code:

```
var tempunix = arr[j][i];
dateOfBirth = moment(tempunix).format("DD-MMM-YYYY");
```

And here's the result from the browser:

```
dateOfBirth "30-Dec-1969"
tempunix -133344000
arr[j][i]-133344000
```

When I use the online converter, -133344000 shows 10Oct65.  Has someone else encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the time in milli seconds.

```
moment(-133344000000)
```

Alternatively, moment.unix() variant if you want to use time in seconds.

```
moment.unix(-133344000)
```